# Exporting Members of Multiple Security Groups within an OU Path to a CSV

Tags: powershell

I am trying to export the users of security groups into a .csv file. However, I have a few conditions that I am struggling with.

So far, I have this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Write-Host 'This script is used to check what users have access to a particular network drive.' `n 'Please wait...'

Start-Sleep 4

Write-Host 'Below is a list of the available DJ network drive security groups:'

Start-Sleep 3

Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Network Drives,OU=DJ Security Groups,OU=Security Groups,DC=lan,DC=mydomain,DC=com" | FL Name

Start-Sleep 3

$SecurityGroup = Read-Host -Prompt 'From the list, please enter a security group name which corresponds to the network drive you wish to check'

Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $SecurityGroup | select name |export-csv
-Path C:\SQLApps\GroupMembers.csv -Append

Start-Sleep 1

Write-Host  'This script has completed successfully and has been exported to C:\SQLApps\GroupMembers.csv'
```

This displays the correct groups.

When I enter one of the security groups in the list and press enter it performs exactly how it should and then exports them to a .CSV which results in the correct users. However, what I would like to do is to export all of the members of each of the groups returned within screenshot one into a single .csv file but list them under their respective SG. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Network Drives,OU=DJ Security Groups,OU=Security Groups,DC=lan,DC=cyclops-electronics,DC=com"

$Report = foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    $Members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group
    foreach ($Member in $Members) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            GroupName = $Group.Name
            MemberName = $Member.Name
        }
    }
}

$Report | Export-Csv -Path C:\SQLApps\GroupMembers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys by forcing yourself using powershell for everything you put yourself in hell-like situation sometimes.

CSVDE was provided by Microsoft for this purpose (AD export to CSV) especially.

One command line: `csvde.exe -f <CSV_filename> -r "<my_ldap_filer>" -d search_base -p <my_scope> -s <my_servername>[:<LDAP_port>] -l <attribute_to_list> -X`

JF